# How to add touch events to a class?.. prefereably through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you do something like the following?

```
$('.myDivs').ontouchstart(function(){
alert('touch');
})
```

the only way I appear to be able to implement touch events is using javascript.. like so

```
document.getElementById('singleDiv').addEventListener("touchstart",touchHandler, false);
```

However I would like to implement this to a class, rather than an id... therefore is there a way to do it using jquery like the above example?....

I have found the answer:

```
$('.myDivs').bind('touchstart', function (event) { alert('touch');});
```

Kind regards J

Comment: I have struggled with this for ages, and then 2 mins later I find the answer: $('.myDivs').bind('touchstart', function (event) { alert('touch');});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.4.2, the following works fine for me:

```
$('.classname').live('touchstart', function(e) {  
    // Do whatever you want here...
});
```

Or for the latest versions of jQuery:

```
$('.classname').on('touchstart', function(e) {  
    // Do whatever you want here...
});
```

Comment: Tested them out, and both work great as long as you have as specified in the answer the correct versions of jquery (which I didnt!) thanks Ben

Answer (score 0):

just select the class instead of the id:

```
    document.getElementsByClassName('myClass').addEventListener(...);
```

please not that this selector will not work in IE. For IE you could use jQuery:

```
    $('.myClass').on("click",function(){});
```

Comment: The `onclick` event is different to the `ontouchstart` event in most mobile browsers. iOS for example executes click events after a slight delay (the browser needs to first check if the user is doing something native such as scrolling, zooming and so forth).

Comment: I wasn't even considering the kind of event he needed, the problem, as i saw it, was to select the class.

Comment: Thanks Th0rndike, but document.getElementsByClassName('myClass').addEventListener doesn't seem to work for some reason... I like you thought it would.